# oracle sql developer sp con consulta select no devuelve datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, select, stored-procedure

Estoy desarrollando un reporte para el trabajo, normalmente utilizaba SQL SERVER pero ahora estamos trabajando con el Oracle Sql Developer, el porblema esta en que no me devuelve datos o estoy declarando o conectando mal las variables Script Sp

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_RESUM_GEST_AUTO ( 
p_establecimiento IN NUMBER, -- Referencia a la tabla AUTORIZACAO_CONVENIO: CD_ESTABELECIMENTO 
p_convenio IN NUMBER, -- Referencia a la tabla AUTORIZACAO_CONVENIO: CD_CONVENIO 
p_categoria IN NUMBER, -- Referencia a la tabla AGENDA_CONSULTA: CD_CATEGORIA 
p_estado IN VARCHAR2, -- Referencia a la tabla AUTORIZACAO_CONVENIO: IE_TIPO_AUTORIZACAO 
p_fecha_desde IN DATE, -- Fecha de referencia para filtrar registros 
p_fecha_hasta IN DATE, -- Fecha de referencia para filtrar registros 
p_id_atencion IN NUMBER, -- Referencia a la tabla AUTORIZACAO_CONVENIO: NR_ATENDIMENTO 
p_id_persona_fisica IN NUMBER, -- Referencia a la tabla AUTORIZACAO_CONVENIO: CD_PESSOA_FISICA v_Autorizaciones out SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
IS BEGIN 
open v_Autorizaciones for
 SELECT AC.CD_CONVENIO AS CD_CONVENIO_AC,
 C.DS_CONVENIO AS DS_CONVENIO_C,
 EA.DS_ESTAGIO AS DS_ESTAGIO_EA,
 E.CD_ESTABELECIMENTO AS CD_ESTABELECIMENTO_E,
 E.NM_FANTASIA_ESTAB AS NM_FANTASIA_ESTAB_E,
 AGC.CD_CATEGORIA AS CD_CATEGORIA_AGC
 --COUNT(1) AS CANTIDAD_REGISTROS 
FROM autorizacao_convenio ac
 INNER JOIN agenda_consulta agc ON ac.nr_atendimento = agc.nr_atendimento 
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica pf ON ac.cd_pessoa_fisica = pf.cd_pessoa_fisica 
INNER JOIN convenio c ON ac.cd_convenio = c.cd_convenio 
INNER JOIN estagio_autorizacao ea ON ac.nr_seq_estagio = ea.nr_sequencia 
INNER JOIN estabelecimento e ON e.cd_estabelecimento = ac.cd_estabelecimento
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica pf_med ON pf_med.cd_pessoa_fisica = ac.cd_medico_solicitante 
INNER JOIN medico m ON ac.cd_medico_solicitante = m.cd_pessoa_fisica -- 
INNER JOIN SETOR_ATENDIMENTO SA ON SA.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO = AC.CD_SETOR_RESP 
INNER JOIN classif_autorizacao clas_a ON clas_a.nr_sequencia = ac.nr_seq_classif 
INNER JOIN tipo_acomodacao ta ON ta.cd_tipo_acomodacao = ac.cd_tipo_acomodacao 
LEFT JOIN autorizacao_convenio_hist ach ON ach.nr_atendimento = ac.nr_atendimento 
LEFT JOIN tiss_retorno_autorizacao tra ON ac.nr_sequencia = tra.nr_seq_autorizacao 
LEFT JOIN procedimento_autorizado pa ON ac.nr_atendimento = pa.nr_atendimento 
INNER JOIN "TASY"."VALOR_DOMINIO" vd ON ac.ie_tipo_autorizacao = vd.vl_dominio 
LEFT JOIN usuario us ON us.nm_usuario = ac.nm_usuario 
WHERE VD.CD_DOMINIO = 1377 
AND ((AC.CD_ESTABELECIMENTO = :P_ESTABLECIMIENTO) or (:P_ESTABLECIMIENTO = 0)) 
AND ((AC.CD_CONVENIO = :P_CONVENIO) or (:P_CONVENIO = 0)) 
AND ((AGC.CD_CATEGORIA = :P_CATEGORIA) or (:P_CATEGORIA = 0 )) 
AND ((AC.IE_TIPO_AUTORIZACAO = :P_ESTADO) or (:P_ESTADO = 0)) 
AND ((AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO >= :P_FECHA_DESDE AND AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO <= NVL(:P_FECHA_HASTA, AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO)) OR (AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO <= NVL(:P_FECHA_DESDE, AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO) AND AC.DT_AUTORIZACAO <= :P_FECHA_HASTA)) AND ((AC.NR_ATENDIMENTO = :P_ID_ATENCION ) or (:P_ID_ATENCION = 0))
AND ((AC.cd_pessoa_fisica = :P_ID_PERSONA_FISICA) or (:P_ID_PERSONA_FISICA = 0)) 
GROUP BY AC.CD_CONVENIO, C.DS_CONVENIO, EA.DS_ESTAGIO, E.CD_ESTABELECIMENTO, E.NM_FANTASIA_ESTAB, AGC.CD_CATEGORIA 
ORDER BY ac.CD_CONVENIO, c.DS_CONVENIO, AGC.CD_CATEGORIA; 
END SP_RESUM_GEST_AUTO;```

**Medio de ejecutacion** 
```VAR rc REFCURSOR;

BEGIN sp_detalle_gest_auto( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, :rc ); END; / PRINT rc;
````

Estuve tratando de correr el procedimient pero me suele devlover errores como:

> ```
> Error que empieza en la línea: 51 del comando :
> BEGIN
>   sp_detalle_gest_auto(
>     58,
>     1004,
>     1,
>     '6',
>     to_date('01/09/2023','dd/mm/yyyy'),
>     to_date('25/11/2023','dd/mm/yyyy'),
>     141775,
>     83158,
>     :rc
>   );
> END;
> Informe de error -
> ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 3:
> PLS-00905: el objeto TASY.SP_DETALLE_GEST_AUTO no es válido
> ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 3:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
>
> RC
> ```

Comment: ¿Recompilaste _SP_DETALLE_GEST_AUTO_? Hazlo antes de compilar _SP_RESUM_GEST_AUTO_.